# I can't get image preview to work on filepond

Tags: filepond

I have done literally everything to make it work but it is not working yet

I loaded from cdn just as it is in the preview documentation

```
<!-- add to document <head> -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond- 
plugin-image-preview.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- add before </body> -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image- 
preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
```

To enhance into a filepond element I have

```
<script>
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement );
</script>
```

and lastly

```
<input type="file">
```

It just shows up as a file and not with image preview. What am I missing?

Comment: Please note that it's always good to add more details to your question, plus what you've tried so far with code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugins have not been registered with FilePond.

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FilePond Plugin Image Preview Demo</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <input type="file"/>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>

    <script>
    // Register the plugin with FilePond
    FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);

    // Get a reference to the file input element
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

    // Create the FilePond instance
    const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Live demo here: https://pqina.github.io/filepond-plugin-image-preview/

I'm looking at [the docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-preview/) and I see how this is confusing, will improve them as soon as I have some time.

Comment: I tried it inside the enhancement script and this way `<script type="text/javascript">
FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview)</script>

<script>
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement );

</script>` no luck yet

Comment: Copy and pasted it exactly. This time it does not change into a pond at all. Except I remove the preview plugin registration. I put it back, and it is the normal regular browser file input field

Comment: The image preview plugin URL had a breaking space in it. Removed.

Comment: Breaking it off has been my nightmare. Thanks

Comment: @Rik I get this error blob:https://localhost:7116/c54bb1f5-85dd-4293-93e3-43ecf09b1af4:1          GET blob:https://localhost:7116/c54bb1f5-85dd-4293-93e3-43ecf09b1af4 net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)